How to gather sysdate -1 using iMacros?
I am currently trying to learn about how to get the current date and time in iMacros chrome extension
{{!NOW:yyyy/mm/dd}}  this is for the current date
have any thoughts on how to make i current date -1 (yesterday's date)?
thank you so much in advance!

For Date manipulation, you'll probably want/need to use the JS Date Object inside the iMacros EVAL() Command. // (Can't link to the EVAL() Command, the whole iMacros Wiki Site seems to be a bit dead now (May 2024), redirecting to itself... (Link I tried, might work again "later" if my feedback comes through to fix it...))
